# SLD Filter function if_then_else argument #2 - expected type Object

Tags: geoserver, geotools, sld

I'm facing a problem with the GeoServer SLD XML.

My XML code is as follows:

```
<Fill>
    <CssParameter name="fill">
        <ogc:Function name="if_then_else">
            <ogc:Function name="isNull">
                <ogc:PropertyName>LTE_RSRP</ogc:PropertyName>
            </ogc:Function>
            <ogc:Literal>#FF0000</ogc:Literal>
            <ogc:Function name="Interpolate">

                <ogc:PropertyName>LTE_RSRP</ogc:PropertyName>

                <ogc:Literal>-80</ogc:Literal>
                <ogc:Literal>#ff0000</ogc:Literal>

                <ogc:Literal>-70</ogc:Literal>
                <ogc:Literal>#00ff00</ogc:Literal>

                <ogc:Literal>-60</ogc:Literal>
                <ogc:Literal>#0000ff</ogc:Literal>

                <ogc:Literal>color</ogc:Literal>

            </ogc:Function>
        </ogc:Function>
    </CssParameter>
    <CssParameter name="fill-opacity">0.3</CssParameter>
</Fill>
```

My intention is as follows:

- If LTE_RSRP is null, fill with #FF0000.
- Else, interpolate the color.

But when the above XML is applied, the following error occurs.

`ERROR [geotools.rendering] - Filter Function problem for function if_then_else argument #2 - expected type Object`

Here, argument #2 is the function Interpolate. (argument counting starts from 0, according to the geotools source code.) It seems that the return value of the function Interpolate is not an object.

Is this intentional? Or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This is intentional - how could a function that interpolates a colour map return an object? What you want to do can be done using Rules and Filters so something (untested) like this should work:

```
<Rule>
<ogc:Filter>
    <ogc:PropertyIsNull>
       <ogc:PropertyName>LTE_RSRP</ogc:PropertyName>
    </ogc:PropertyIsNull>
</ogc:Filter>
  <ogc:PolygonSymbolizer>
   ....
   <Fill>
      ....
 </Rule>
 <Rule>
   <ElseFilter/>
   <PolygonSymbolizer>
     ....
     <Fill>
       <ogc:Function name="Interpolate">
            <ogc:PropertyName>LTE_RSRP</ogc:PropertyName>
            <ogc:Literal>-80</ogc:Literal>
            <ogc:Literal>#ff0000</ogc:Literal>
            <ogc:Literal>-70</ogc:Literal>
            <ogc:Literal>#00ff00</ogc:Literal>
            <ogc:Literal>-60</ogc:Literal>
            <ogc:Literal>#0000ff</ogc:Literal>
            <ogc:Literal>color</ogc:Literal>
        </ogc:Function>
       ....
```

Comment: I don't think so. The interpolate function returns a color, which is an object. In JavaScript, my intention can be expressed as follows: `return (LTE_RSRP === null) ? '#FF0000' : Interpolate(LTE_RSRP, interpolateOption);`

Comment: Anyways I've walked around the problem with multiple Rules. But the resulting XML code is more (unnecessarily, in my opinion) verbose.

Comment: that's life with SLD :-)